# Partial derivative of an inner product with a $C^1$ function

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $h \in C^1(\mathbb{R}^m,\mathbb{R})$ be a function depending on $u \in U \subset \mathbb{R}^m$, U convex, and $w \in \mathbb{R}^m$.

I found the following expression:
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial w}\frac{\nabla h(u)}{\|\nabla h(u)\|}\langle \frac{\nabla h(u)}{\|\nabla h(u)\|},w\rangle = \frac{\nabla h(u)}{\|\nabla h(u)\|}\langle \frac{\nabla h(u)}{\|\nabla h(u)\|},\cdot\rangle=\frac{\nabla h(u)}{\|\nabla h(u)\|}\bigg (\frac{\nabla h(u)}{\|\nabla h(u)\|}\bigg )^*\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times m} .$$
where the $\cdot$ indicates the presence of $dw$, $\langle,\rangle$ the inner product on $\mathbb{R}^m$ and $\bigg (\frac{\nabla h(u)}{\|\nabla h(u)\|}\bigg )^*=adj\bigg (\frac{\nabla h(u)}{\|\nabla h(u)\|}\bigg )$.

I don't really understand the meaning of this, should we treat the expression ''$\frac{\partial}{\partial w}\frac{\nabla h(u)}{\|\nabla h(u)\|}\langle \frac{\nabla h(u)}{\|\nabla h(u)\|},w\rangle$'' as a sort of $\lambda w$ with $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: What is the $*$ supposed to represent in the $h(u) h(u)^{*}$?

Comment: it's the adjoint of $h(u)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}\newcommand{\transpose}{^{\top}}\newcommand{\myd}{\mathrm{d}}$Since you are working in $\R^m$, you can just say $x^{\ast} = x\transpose$ for every $x\in \R^m$.

First of all the equality that confuses you has nothing to do with the function $h$. You can just replace $\frac{\nabla h(u)}{\|h(u)\|}$ by any $x\in \R^m$. The function you want to derive is
$$
f:\left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
\R^m &\to& \R^m,\\
w&\mapsto& \langle x, w \rangle x,
\end{array}\right.
$$
where $x$ is any fixed element in $\R^m$.
Note that you can write
$$
f(w) = \begin{pmatrix}\sum_{i=1}^m x_i w_i x_1 \\ \sum_{i=1}^m x_i w_i x_2 \\ \vdots \\ \sum_{i=1}^m x_i w_i x_m \end{pmatrix}
$$
Therefore
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial w_j}f(w) =
\begin{pmatrix} x_j x_1 \\ x_j x_2 \\ \vdots \\ x_j x_m \end{pmatrix}
\quad \text{and}\quad
\myd f(w) =
\begin{pmatrix}
x_1 x_1 & x_2 x_1 & \dots & x_m x_1 \\
x_1 x_2 & x_2 x_2 & \dots & x_m x_2 \\
\vdots &  &\ddots & \vdots\\
x_1 x_m & \dots & & x_m x_m
\end{pmatrix}
= x\cdot x\transpose
.
$$
Now replace $x$ by $\frac{\nabla h(u)}{\|h(u)\|}$ and you have your result.